# What is the way to verify beforehand if a function works for any version of java jre?

Tags: java

I'm  relatively new using java and recently tried some of my codes in other computers (with different versions of jre or jdk)  ...for example, i've been trying to know if  the function  .newLine() works for jre1.6 ...but i can't find it

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(directorio523+"tabla1.txt"), "utf-8"));
writer.write("something");
writer.newLine();
```

So, is there a web wich identify that or a command for linux to put?

Comment: Javadocs for the versions you need to run your code on

Answer (score 4):

Check [the class's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). In this case, the class is noted as being present "since JDK1.1", and the method doesn't have a more specific date, so anything since Java 1.1 should support it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply consult the API for JDK 1.6 :

[It does exists.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine())